Is it possible to kill a warm state lambda such that next time lambda starts in cold state?
I have a frontend app that is calling an API that uses lambda in backend, there is some issue occurring randomly (95% of the time it works fine) in my frontend app and after a lot of debugging i believe the issue occurs when the lambda starts from cold state (i.e. slightly longer execution time)
To debug more from this point i want the lambda to always start from cold phase. How to achieve this?
Extra information
Might not be required but my frontend is using Angular and backend is based on node.js.
Tried Solutions
Currently, i wait for few minutes such that lambda becomes inactive and next call starts from cold phase.

Redeploy the Lambda function code or modify an environment variable or other configuration setting for the Lambda function.

Lambda does re-use containers (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/). So your application will need to take that into consideration when designing/deploying your application. I dont think you can control the lambda invocation (i.e. if its to happen from a fresh instance (cold start) or re-use from a container that has been hibernated)
